# Непонятный отступ внизу страницы

Tags: отступы, html, вёрстка

Здравствуйте.
Проблема вот в чем, внизу страницы, под футером, есть отступ. Пробивал через Firebug - ничего не нашел. Стер практически весь css код,думал методом вырезание найду что-то. Не решил проблемы. Текста нет, обрезал до такого http://jsfiddle.net/M8ZPu/ .

Нашел подобное на другом сайте http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

В firebug вижу различные элементы,которых нет в коде
в head(е)

```
<script id="dkr" type="text/javascript" src="http://desktopm.info/module/igwdn.js"/>
```

в body в самом низу 
`<img src="http://gn.dataur.ru/favicon.gif?6016" id="dst" height="1" width="1"/>`

Не знаю влияют ли они, но и их смысла понять не могу.

Но важная проблема остается за внешним отступом снизу.

---

Выяснилось что это у меня что-то с компьютером.
Так как у других все нормально показывает.
А у меня в хроме и мозиле беда. НО в IE отступа нет. Бред какой-то.

Comment: > Не знаю влияют ли они, но и их смысла понять не могу.

Скорее всего, они добавлены расширениями

Answer (score 0):

```
#main{
min-height:100%;
margin: 0 0 -70px;
}
```

У вас стилях написано, что растягивать контейнер на всю высоту, кроме последних 70 пикселей. В итоге, на последние 70 пикселей располагается футер. Отсюда и возникает пустое место снизу. Попробуйте изменить -70px на другое значение :)

**Добавлено**

Да, и закрывайте div.

[Вот попробовал](http://jsfiddle.net/IVsevolod/M8ZPu/1/), если это не то что вы хотели, уточните вопрос :)

Comment: Я уже пробовал. Я закомментировал этот марджин и выключил футер. не получается.

Изначально, высота футера 70 px. поэтому там стоит -70px;
Т.е. тянет на себя, чего там от этого вообще отступ может быть? чтот не пойму

Comment: @Виет Обновил ответ. http://jsfiddle.net/IVsevolod/M8ZPu/1/ тут правильно?

Comment: Принцип остался. но у меня вообще текста нет. футера нет. а отступ есть. я думаю если бы проблема тут была, то при удалении футера и марджина - все бы решилось

Да я закрываю div. просто при добавлении в  http://jsfiddle.net забыл добавить.

Comment: Хочу заметить, страница имеет 100% высоту + отступ. То есть появляется скроллбар.

Answer (score 0):

У меня причиной такого отступа стали невидимые элементы lightbox, которые до активации перемещались именно вниз документа, а после активации (щелкания по любой картинке) отступ убирался до перезагрузки страницы. Я поставила `display: none;` на основной контейнер lightbox - и проблема решилась.

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема на своём сайте. Заходил на сайт и был отступ в самом внизу после тэга `footer`. Просмотрел страницу через браузер - исследовать элемент. Заметил что высота тэга `body` слишком большая. Через CSS стиль уменьшил высоту `body`, проблема исчезла.